# HQL query with several joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I have the following relation of three classes:

```
   @Entity
    public class User{

       @OnetoMany
       List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    }

    @Entity
    public class Attribute{
       @ManyToOne
       AttributeType attributeType;

    }

    @Entity
    public class AttributeType{

       @Column
       String type;
    }
```

One user can have n attributes of m types.

I need to create HQL query which will return all Atribute Types `List<AttributeType>` of specific user attributes.

For example user has attribute a of type t, atribute b of type t and attribute c of type t1.
I need to return `List<AttributeType>` which will contain t and t1.

Please help. I just got lost in this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall map Attribute to User many to one relation, so the following query is what you need:

```
select distinct atr.attributeType
  from Attribute atr
 where atr.user = :user
```

I think the following query will work too:

```
select distinct atrs.attributeType
  from User as user
  join user.attributes as atrs   
 where user.id = :user_id
```